# JSP pass variable from jsp request form to java back to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do I pass form info from jsp to java to jsp again.

I have this jsp form that when I submit it, it is passed to another jsp page directly that displays those info. But then I want to process those information first in a java file before passing it again to jsp.

I do something like this in jsp..

```
  <form method="POST" action="process.java" >
     ....
  </form>
```

then on process.java I use request.setAttribute("data") to stored the processed data. But how do I redirect it back to an html view file? Sorry new user here.

Sorry this should be really a common question but i just want a simple answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to POST your form data to a servlet which is mapped to particular URL for example `/process` and container will delegate that request to mapped Servlet

---

**See**

- [`servlet` info with example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: is a servlet neccessary? Im just doing this for a small program. :(

Comment: Yes you cannot POST to a java class like the way you are intending, servlet is much better way to go for, see the example linked, its simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect in `HttpServletResponse`:

```
response.sendRedirect("next.jsp"); // next.jsp is your next jsp you want to show
```

By the way, your Java has to extend Servlet API interface to be invoked.